# I get "SyntaxError" for rst2pdf command after installing RST2PDF in Windows 7

Tags: rst2pdf

After I install RST2PDF in Windows 7, and run the command `rst2pdf` or `rst2pdf -h`, it says

> SyntxError: Invalid syntax

I installed rst2pdf V.93 using PIP and have set the path to scripts in python directory.

Here is the error:

> c:>rst2pdf Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Scripts\rst2pd
>   f-script.py", line 9, in 
>       load_entry_point('rst2pdf===0.93.dev-r0', 'console_scripts', 'rst2pdf')()   File
>   "C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packa
>   ges\pkg_resources__init__.py", line 558, in load_entry_point
>       return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)   File "C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packa
>   ges\pkg_resources__init__.py", line 2682, in load_entry_point
>       return ep.load()   File "C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packa
>   ges\pkg_resources__init__.py", line 2355, in load
>       return self.resolve()   File "C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packa
>   ges\pkg_resources__init__.py", line 2361, in resolve
>       module = **import**(self.module_name, fromlist=['**name**'], level=0)   File
>   "C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packa
>   ges\rst2pdf\createpdf.py", line 695
>       except ValueError, v:
>                        ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for exception handling changed with python 3: instead of `except ValueError, v` one must use `except ValueError as v`.

Apparently, rst2pdf has no support for python3. To use it, you must have python2.7 installed. Some attempts have been made to port rst2pdf, but the efforts seem to have stalled.

Alternatively, you may try to use pandoc, as suggested [here](https://github.com/poldracklab/mriqc/issues/139)